# Java Agent DEvelopment Framework

Tags: java, agents-jade

How could I hide the Remote Agent Management GUI and avoid it to appear after I've compiled a project developed between java(netbeans) and jade?

Answer (score 0):

The command line option -gui launches the GUI. This GUI is an instance of Jade Remote Monitoring Agent, RMA. The RMA GUI, may impact system performance. So, do not use -gui if you wish not to run the GUI. Typically, the RMA GUI is not used at deployment time if considering the performance.